# Refresh google map of my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added a `googleMap` to my application successfully. Now i need to add a refresh button to the `map` so that it gets refreshed. I have added the `button`, but i don't know how to refresh the `map`.

Is there any predefined method that i could use to refresh the `map`. Help ??

Comment: what do you want to do as refresh? - setting default zoom level/removing all annotations????

Comment: setting default zoom level, and adding new annotations if they are available

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing predefined for REFRESH - what  you are looking for in the MapKit. you need to remove old annotations and have to add the new ones manually(from your own code) for zooming you need to create a span on your own to set it to any value you like (that's also to be done by your own code).